# Should I use both HtmlEncode and JavaScriptStringEncode if inside HTML <script> tag?

Tags: asp.net, .net, encoding

I want to render in .NET a string destined for Javascript, say:

```
<html>
...
<script>
   alert('<%= this.MyStringHere %>');
</script>
</html>
```

How should I encode MyStringHere?  Do I need `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(unencodedString))` or is just `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(unencodedString)` sufficient?  Or are both wrong?

Feel free to mention alternative server tag <% solutions in your answer too, but I'm looking for the code-based solution, the example is a little contrived.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only need to encode the script for JS use, no need to double encode using HTML encoding. Just HTML encoding will not work either because it will not encode `\n` etc.

```
<script>
   alert(<%=HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(this.MyStringHere, true)%>);
   alert("<%=HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(this.MyStringHere, false)%>");
</script>
```

Note that `JavaScriptStringEncode` will not add the double quotes by default - [see official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

If you have server-side JSON package installed, you could also use that - and it will also work for arrays, dictionaries etc.. Note that it will also add quotes for strings so you do not add them yourself.

You also have to remember that you cannot use `<%: text %>` syntax since that does the HTML encoding. In MVC Razor views you even have to explicitly disable HTML encoding by using `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(...))`.

Comment: According to [the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/httpserverutility.cs#L1534), the default is to *not* include the quotes.